# Serializing objects (like std::wstring) with basic_stringstream for transmission over TCP

Tags: c++, buffer, stringstream

I'm working on a network messenger for sending and receiving `Message` objects over TCP/IP. Normally, messages contain primitives, `std::string`s; or vectors of strings however, there are cases where I need to send UTF16 Unicode `std::wstring`s.

To my knowledge, from a TCP perspective, everything will be transfered as an array of bytes (`char`) anyway, so it should be possible to just bytewise send these `wstring`s over. After receiving and deserializing, I'm force casting the data into it's corresponding messageType which is stated in the header.

A Message look like this:

```
class ConcreteMessage: public Message
{
private:  
    std::wstring m_myString;
    int aPrimiteVariable;

public:
    // serializes the messages variables and sends it to the MemoryStream
    void save(util::MemoryStream& out)
    {
         out << aPrimiteVariable;

         size_t len = m_myString.size();      // length of the string (number of wchar_t's)
         out << len;

         size_t sz = m_myString.size() * sizeof(wchar_t);    // effective size of the string (len * 2 bytes on Windows)
         out << sz;

         /// send the wstring to the MemoryStream             
         if (sz)
            out.write((const unsigned char*)m_myString.c_str(), sz);

    }

    /// does the same thing in reverse to deserialize the message. Must be done in the exact same order!
    void load(util::MemoryStream& in)
    {
       in > aPrimiteVariable;

       size_t len;
       in >> len;
       m_myString.resize(len);

       size_t sz;
       in >> sz;

       if (sz)
          in.read((unsigned char*)&m_myString.front(), sz);
    }
};
```

I'm using an extended `basic_stringstream` for de-/serialization:

```
#pragma once

#include <sstream>

namespace util {

class MemoryStream : public std::basic_stringstream<unsigned char>
{
    typedef std::basic_stringstream<unsigned char> TBase;

public:
    MemoryStream()
    {
    }

    MemoryStream(const unsigned char* begin_, const unsigned char* end_)
    : TBase(std::basic_string<unsigned char>(begin_, end_))
    {
    }

    template<typename T>
    MemoryStream& operator <<(T i) {
        return writePrimitive(i);
    }

    template<typename T>
    MemoryStream& operator >>(T& i) {
        return readPrimitive(i);
    }

    template<typename T>
    MemoryStream& operator <<(std::basic_string<T> s) {
        size_t len = s.length();
        writePrimitive(len);
        write(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(s.c_str()), len * sizeof(T));
    }

    template<typename T>
    MemoryStream& operator >>(std::basic_string<T>& s) {
        size_t len = 0;
        readPrimitive(len);

        util::ScopedArray<T> buf(new T[len + 1]);
        memset(buf.get(), 0, (len + 1) * sizeof(T));

        read(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(buf.get()), len * sizeof(T));

        s = buf.get();
    }

private:

    template<typename T>
    MemoryStream& writePrimitive(T t)
    {
        write(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&t), sizeof(t));
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename T>
    MemoryStream& readPrimitive(T& t)
    {
        read(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&t), sizeof(t));
        return *this;
    }
};

template<typename T>
inline
MemoryStream& operator <<(MemoryStream& st, T t)
{
    return st.operator <<(t);
}

template<typename T>
inline
MemoryStream& operator >>(MemoryStream& st, T& t)
{
    return st.operator >>(t);
}

}
```

Notice that this class inherits `std::basic_stringstream<unsigned char>` and not `wchar_t`

Now, when receiving such data, I need to cast it to the corresponding Message Class:

```
if (ConcreteMessage* msg = dynamic_cast<ConcreteMessage*>(m))
// etc....
```

First of all: everything works so far (surprisingly). However, there are tons of `reinterpret_cast`s and `dynamic_cast`s, and it feel kind of dirty.

Do you see any serious problems in this approach?

I'm always hearing that you should never use `reinterpret_cast` and 'dynamic_cast', but is there really a way to avoid them when doing such a serialization proccess on distributed systems?

Comment: Just a personal reflection on your design, I don't think using inheritance is a good match here, [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) might be a better idea. (Also see [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).)

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at this pattern. You mean the Message inheritance? basically the only thing that is done in the inherited Message class is storing a Type variable indicating the type of the message and give them a common interface for "load" and "save"

Comment: Ah no, I mean the `MemoryStream` class.

Comment: Ah ok thank you, I will take a look at it

Comment: A note about endianess: if you're planning to use this serialization to a broad range of computer systems, the byte order might be different and doing blanket conversion to char array and back will not work correctly.

Comment: Thank you for this hint; Its planned to work only on windows computers - I supposed and hope they all handle it in a little-endian way?

Comment: You could also use `string.data()` instead of `string.c_str()`. The difference is that `string.data()` should just immediately return the existing data, but `string.c_str()` may have to append a NUL character first. The standard does not require the string to maintain a NUL-terminated value internally.